# left of her own volition

Tags: meaning

In context below, does the sentence "Left of her own volition" mean "she went away willingly " or "she was deprivated of her will"?

> In the garage, she unlocks the Honda, which she bought before they met and is registered in her name. He can’t—surely— ask the police to put a call out if she’s driving her own car? She’s watched enough crime shows.
> Left of her own volition, they’ll say.
>
> Volition is a nice word. It makes her think of flying.

Comment: Have you checked any [dictionaries](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/volition)?

Comment: Yes, many dictionaries. But the construction is confuse for me. "left" with meaning of "go away" or "deprived of"?

Comment: It's really not obvious from your question which word you're having trouble with. Please re-cast to make it clearer.

Answer (score 1):

The word "volition" means "will", as in "free will", and in this context "of" means something like "according to" or "following". So "left of her own volition" means "left according to her own free will".

A simpler way to phrase it is:

> She left willingly.

This means, she wasn't coerced or forced to leave. She left by choice.